# Не работает отношение one-to-many между таблицами

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Работаю из Spring Boot и Hibernate. В базе данных создал таблицу пользователей и таблицу "желаний" этих пользователей, промапил сущности, установил зависимости, в базу данных добавил данные.

Здесь описую сущность для таблицы users

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "userID")
private int userID;

@Column(name = "username")
private String username;

@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private List<Wishes> wishes;

@Column(name = "authorities")
private String authorities;

public User() {}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public List<Wishes> getWishes() {
    return wishes;
}

public void setWishes(List<Wishes> wishes) {
    this.wishes = wishes;
}

public String getAuthorities() {
    return authorities;
}

public void setAuthorities(String authorities) {
    this.authorities = authorities;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return userID + " " + username + " " + password;
}
}
```

Здесь описую сущность для таблицы wishes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "wishes")
public class Wishes {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "wishID")
private int wishID;


@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "userID")
private User user;

@Column(name = "wishName")
private String wishName;
@Column(name = "link")
private String link;

public int getWishID() {
    return wishID;
}

public void setWishID(int wishID) {
    this.wishID = wishID;
}

public User getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getWishName() {
    return wishName;
}

public void setWishName(String wishName) {
    this.wishName = wishName;
}

public String getLink() {
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return wishID + " " + wishName + " " + link;
}
}
```

Проблема в том, что когда я обращаюсь к методу getWishes() класса User то я падаю по LazyInitialisationException, когда устанавливаю fetch = FetchType.EAGER у параметра private List wishes, то программа зацыкливается и начинает повторно выводить все "желания" пользователя, ну и падает по OutofMemoryError.
В контроллере для проверки работоспособности кода написал метод

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/")
public ResponseEntity<List<Wishes>> getMainPage() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User user = (org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User)authentication.getPrincipal();

    User user1 = manageUser.findbyUsername(user.getUsername());

    return new ResponseEntity<List<Wishes>>(user1.getWishes(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где может быть ошибка.

Comment: 'то программа зацыкливается и начинает повторно выводить все "желания" ' В какой части кода она именно зацикливается?

Comment: Продебажыл и выяснил, что, как я понял, метод ResponseEntity начинает идти по всем геттерам класа Wishes и когда попадает на геттер getUser, его кидает на класс User, отуда опять геттером на класс Вишер, ну и покругу. Почему так - не знаю, посмотрел, в тамймлифе такого нету, когда ему говорю что вывести, то он сразу идёт в toString.

Comment: попробуй удалить `toString()` методы из объектов и перезапусти по новой.

Comment: А какой смысл, если дебаг показал, что методы toString даже не вызываются?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема зацикливания возникает не на стороне `JPA/Hibernate`, а на стороне "движка" `REST`-сервиса. `Hibernate` "знает" о отношениях между сущностями и не входит в цикл, а `REST`-сервис этого не "знает" и методично вычитывает зацикленную связь - бесконечно. Требуется указать "движку" что не следует вычитывать поле `user` сущности `Wishes`. В вопросе не указано, какая именно реализация `REST` используется, например, у `Jackson` для этого есть аннотация `org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnore`. Некоторые другие `REST`-"движки" "понимают" аннотацию `javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient`. Можно добавить их обе. Код будет выглядеть так:

```
@JsonIgnore
@XmlTransient
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "userID")
private User user;
```

PS Сущность `Wishes` логичнее назвать `Wish`, ведь один экземпляр сущности отражает одну запись.

Comment: Да, действительно, может сработать, вешал эту аннотацию на поле wishes в классе user, то выводился только user. Так как вы порекомендовали писать не пробовал, не знаю почему, но поверю что сработает))